# Explicitly, how can I get s3fs to open a gz file in AWS? Glue/S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

Using AWS glue and AWS s3 and s3fs, I've come up with the following (among other attempts). I even see the examples at https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but they're not getting me there.

```html
key = 'https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/datalake-sbox-landing-55555-us-weast/cloudwatch_logs/prod-coarsair/dt%267D2019-09-11/144221-3837-462d-a2e6-ba300/coarsair-coarsair-144221-3837-462d-a2e6-ba300/000000.gz'
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
with s3.open(key, 'r') as f:
    args_gz_file = f
```

Then it should be as easy as typing "args_gz_file" now, right? Nope. Where am I going wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

The samples show:

```
with fs.open('my-bucket/my-file.txt', 'rb') as f:
```

This suggests that the first parameter is `BUCKET-NAME/KEY`.

However, your code sample shows a URL (`https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/`) instead of a bucket name.

Perhaps try:

```
key = 'datalake-sbox-landing-55555-us-weast/cloudwatch_logs/prod-coarsair/dt%267D2019-09-11/144221-3837-462d-a2e6-ba300/coarsair-coarsair-144221-3837-462d-a2e6-ba300/000000.gz'
```

**Side-note:** It is recommended to use the official AWS SDK or the AWS CLI to access Amazon S3, rather than using `s3fs`. Amazon S3 is an object storage service, not a filesystem.